# Datastore Viewer missing rows for hours, out of sync with frontend

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a tiny python app engine project that exposes an endpoint which creates an instance of a certain `ndb.Model` and then calls `put()` on it, returning the model as JSON.

My frontend is behaving as expected (the models seem to be created and returned, no errors in the HTTP request or logs console), but the Datastore Viewer is wildly out of sync: Only one of the ~30 objects created today is shown (which happens to be the most recent object), and it took ~10 minutes for that to happen.

Datastore Statistics similarly shows only 8 entities of this type (where I expect >30), but the timestamp for this page shows it has not been updated for almost 48 hours despite the claim `Statistics are updated at least once per day`.

I know the datastore is eventually consistent, but this has been going on for several hours; either I have a bug (in my trivial program) or something is up with app engine.

I'm a seasoned engineer but new to app engine; any suggestions for common pitfalls or areas I should look into?

**Edit:** Seems to be a [known/ongoing issue with datastore replication](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/eRRitgIDRYk) that [isn't reported on the status dashboard](https://code.google.com/status/appengine) :-\

Comment: There is a current issue with datastore replication which could affecting consistancy - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/eRRitgIDRYk

Comment: @TimHoffman ah, that must be it, thank you!  I'm new to GAE; is this kind of issue frequent? I checked the status dashboard first (https://code.google.com/status/appengine) and nothing is reported there. (Just looking for anecdotal experience obviously..)

Comment: Also I have found datastore statistics can be a lot more than 24 hours out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Known issue with datastore replication](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/eRRitgIDRYk) at the moment (thanks Tim!)

I guess the lesson is, you probably want to subscribe to [google-appengine-downtime-notify](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify) for notification of outages, since the issue was reported there but not on the [appengine dashboard](https://code.google.com/status/appengine).

Answer (score 1):

I have submitted a new defect report about [Datastore Statistics not updating](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10613) at least once every 24 hours.  Please star it and/or chime in with comments.